# Finding first five digits in a var with Regex

Tags: regex, expression

I have a variable that looks like this:  AF1400006

I want to use regular expressions in order to return the number "14000".
I have gone through many threads here, but none quite seems to get me anywhere.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I don't see what's up with the downvotes, isn't this a forum for asking questions? 
Anyhow, I solved my problem now, thanks for the help :-) For those wondering, I used it in a scanning software called Drivve Image to use parts of a barcode on a document as the name of the output folder. The software uses a unique regex formatting which seemed to be my issue.

Comment: What are the requirements? Maybe you just need to obtain a substring starting with the third character and of the length `str.length-4`?

Comment: With what mean do you expect to "return" that number? Are you using any specific language, or are you using "pure" regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use something like `\d{5}` which will match 5 digits.

Depending on the language you are using you would then access whatever the group matched.

For instance, in Java:

```
        String str ="AF1400006";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{5}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        if(m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group());
```

Which yields the number you are after.

An example of the expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/hY8wD4/1).

Comment: Why do you need a capture group at all? It is good for splitting sometimes, but in this case, there seems to be no such a requirement

Comment: @stribizhev: Old habit I guess. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your string already, but my issue was the formatting of the regex in the software I am using. Read my edit if you want :-)